# running chkdsk /F on a large mounted NTFS image file gets BSOD (Windows Vista)

Tags: windows-vista, iso-image, chkdsk, bsod

Using ddrescue, I've created ISO files from the C: and D: drives on my Windows XP laptop's harddisk (after the laptop stopped booting and chkdsk etc. wouldn't fix it).

I was able to mount the 60 GB D.iso file use OSFmount, and successfully recreated the D: drive on another laptop.

The C.iso image is more problematic. ddrescue left about 3mb unrecovered of 85 GB total, after multiple passes (no big worries about this) and I'm able to mount it with OSFmount on a Windows Vista laptop. However, when I run chkdsk /F /V on the mounted drive (which was mounted as H:), I consistently get a blue screen (BSOD).

CHKDSK makes it through the first three passes, including index fixing and security descriptor fixes, without errors, but triggers a BSOD when it attempts to fix the volume records or bitmap

If I attempt to fix the drive by clicking on Properties->Tools->Error checking->Check Now->Automatically fix file system errors, I get an alert box reading "WIndows was unable to complete the disk check."

I'd try a tool other than OSFMount, but it's the only thing I've found so far that will mount large ISO files, and it has worked for me up to now in this process.

[Update 2011-11-13 18:41 EST] Just ran the same process using the original Windows XP laptop, with a different internal drive, and chkdsk worked like a champ. So the question is still interesting, but decidedly less urgent.

Answer (score 2):

Run the hard drive manufacturers diagnostic software on that hard drive, it may have bad sectors.